# Search A SubString Between Two Points Of A String Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we search and save substring inside a string between two specified values dynamically.
For example if a have the following set of strings.

```
var string1 = "This is.. my ..new string";
var string2 = "This is.. your ..new string";
```

Now what to do if i want to save the subsrting that is between two dots, "my" and "your" in this case, from the string, maybe in another variable or maybe by removing everything except "my". I know it can be possible using indexof("my") but that would not be dynamic.

Comment: You should learn how to use regular expression. That's exactly what you need.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes, i am working for pattern practice and there would always be two dots...

Comment: Regex is what you are looking for. Don't use the "split" solution from below.

Comment: Did not say at all that it would not work

Comment: The "Split solution from below is much easier to fathom. Regexes are great but don't make people who post split solutions for this extremely simple case delete their perfectly valid suggestions. It was in its simplicity `string1.split("..")[1]` without the added removal of whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expression is THE solution for this kind of problems. You can do some google on it. There's lots of documents and tutorials out there.

For your particular question, to get the string in between "..", you can use the following code

```
var match1 = string1.match('\\.\\.\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\.\\.');
match1 = match1 ? match1[1] : false;
var match2 = string2.match('\\.\\.\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\.\\.');
match2 = match2 ? match2[1] : false;
```

Comment: Using `[]` directly after `match()` is always a bad idea as it assumes a match is successful. If not, it will error. You should first check that a match was made.

Comment: @TwilightSun, this is giving me the result and i am trying to understand what you have done. I am weak at regex.

Comment: @TwilightSun this is understandable now..Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this script :D

```
/* I have escaped the dots | you can add the spaces in the delimiter if that is your delimiter like*/
var delimiter = '\\.\\.'; 
var text = "This is.. your ..new ..test.. string";

/* this will match anything between the delimiters and return an array of matched strings*/
var res = text.match(new RegExp(delimiter + '(.*?)' + delimiter,'g'));


/*res will be [' your ', 'test'] */
/* I just realized that it does not match "..new ..", which should be a valid match. */;

/* to remove the delimiter string from your results */
 for(i in res) { 
  res[i]=res[i].replace(new RegExp(delimiter,'g'),'');
 };
 console.log(res);
```